# Time is not correct when exporting a grid to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am trying to export a grid in my asp.net application to excel. When I am trying, time column in grid is  coming as 07:00:00, but in excel it is coming as 00-01-00 7:00. The datatype of the corresponding column in the data source is System.TimeSpan. How to fix this? I want the time column as 07:00:00, so that I can do some calculation in exported excel.

Comment: How do you fill the TimeSpan objects into the Excel cells? Please provide the relevant code part.

Comment: I have created a datatable and assign that table as datasource of the grid. This is the exporting grid. When I am trying to export to pdf, the data is coming perfectly. The problem is in excel exporting